# How to select a random string from a list of strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, list, random

Im trying to generate some dummy data and need to re-apply the logic on every new row.

For Example,
The words are '**Comm**' and '**Resi**'.

The query I am using is as follows;

```
    SELECT SubSkill = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Name
    FROM (
        SELECT RandomGUID = cast(round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (1 - 10) + 10, 2) AS INT) 
            ,'Comm' AS Name 
    UNION ALL   
        SELECT cast(round(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (1 - 10) + 10, 2) AS INT)
            ,'Resi'
        ) NAMES
    ORDER BY RandomGUID
    )
,* FROM Sales2
```

However this gives me either 'Comm' for every record, or 'Resi' for every record on execution. I need it to be randomly selected on each row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it seems to work.

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT *, newid() as nid, newid() as nid2 FROM Sales2)
SELECT  case when cast(nid as varchar(80))  > cast(nid2  as varchar(80)) then 'Comm' else 'Resi' END as fiddle,
* FROM CTE
```

I don't really see why yours wouldn't work, since you also have 2 newID's going on

Answer (score 0):

The problem is over-optimization.  One way to get around this is to use a correlated subquery.  Here is an example:

```
select (select top (1) str
        from (values ('comm'), ('resi')) v2(str)
        where v.x is not null
        order by newid()
       )
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(x);
```

The `where` clause changes the subquery so it gets evaluated each time.

Your query would look exactly the same, except for the outer `from` clause and the correlation clause would obviously use your column names.

Comment: It might also help to give an exact answer to the OP's query.

Comment: This did work however, I couldn't workout how to apply in my scenario above. Thanks for your input.